# UITableView is being reset when I use Custom Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView with 2 text field and a button. If I run the simulator without use custom class, I can see the text fields and button:

[image: correct view without custom class]

But when i use a custom class, my UITable view only display a lot of lines without content:

[image: empty lines with custom class]

[image: Interface Builder]

Here is how I've created my properties:

LoginSceneController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface LoginSceneController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *email;

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *password;

- (IBAction)doLogin;

@end
```

LoginSceneController.m

```
#import "LoginSceneController.h"

@interface LoginSceneController ()

@end

@implementation LoginSceneController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)doLogin {

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                                               NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
     {
         if (data.length > 0 && connectionError == nil)
         {
             NSDictionary *greeting = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                      options:0
                                                                        error:NULL];
             self.email.text = [[greeting objectForKey:@"id"] stringValue];
             self.password.text = [greeting objectForKey:@"content"];
         }
     }];
}
@end
```

The problem happens when I use a custom class (or referencing outlet or add a send event on button).

What is wrong?

edit: I think that I need populate my interface using my custom class because the static content is being lost. Is it possible to be the cause of content being lost?

Comment: When you say use a custom class, can you be more specific or include a screenshot from Interface Builder ?

Comment: @Dylan I've included a screenshot..could you check it, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options when it comes to UITableView and Interface Builder.  You can have a dynamic table view (pretty common) where your code overrides UITableViewController methods like "numberOfRowsInSection" and "cellForRowAtIndexPath". The other option is a static tableview, and that seems like what you want to do (especially since you haven't overridden the two aforementioned methods, and leads to your blank table).  My guess is you need to select "static" for the tableview as shown in the third screenshot in this [tutorial](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/05/07/static-table-views-with-storyboards.html).